# I couldn't edit the origin of an alias using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

My OS is Yosemite 10.10.
I was trying to edit the origin of an existing alias of a folder I have, I wrote this script

```
set theAlias to alias "Users/graphics/Desktop/short"
set newAliasPath to "/Users/graphics/Desktop/testfolder/02"

tell application "Finder"
    set original item of file theAlias to file newAliasPath
end tell
```

but I am getting this error `error "File alias Users/graphics/Desktop/short of «script» wasn’t found." number -43`and I dose not seem to work
any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it works now

```
set theAlias to POSIX file "/Users/graphics/Desktop/short" as alias
set newAliasPath to "/Users/graphics/Desktop/testfolder/01"

tell application "Finder"
    set original item of file theAlias to POSIX file newAliasPath
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The AppleScript `alias` specifer doesn't support POSIX paths.
Just use native HFS paths

```
set desktopFolder to path to desktop as text

set theAlias to alias (desktopFolder & "short:")
set newAliasPath to alias (desktopFolder & "testfolder:02:")

tell application "Finder" to
    set original item of theAlias to newAliasPath
end tell
```